# database already exists please choose a different name

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Here's the case I created this Permias.mdf on another solution that I had and then after that I decided not to use that solution and created a new website from visual studio and copy and paste the .mdf file to be used for this website.

```
Database 'C:\\Permias.mdf' already exists. Choose a different database name.
```

Comment: @Alexander, please clarify how you get this error

Comment: perhaps not all of the references to the original Permias.mdf were removed causing the issue of it already existing

Comment: Yes this is a question... when I tried to view my .aspx page in the browser this shows up

Comment: when I rename it I got the following:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Unable to open the physical file "C:\Users\Aditya Aditama H\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\Permias\App_Data\Permias.mdf". Operating system error 2: "2(The system cannot find the file specified.)".
Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\Aditya Aditama H\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\Permias\App_Data\Permias.mdf' as database 'PermDB'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I finally understand what is happening:

You have project A, and it uses physical file `C:\Permias.mdf`.

Now, you have project B, and you'd like to use `C:\Permias.mdf`, so you paste it again in Visual Studio explorer - but, it already physically exists.

Is this correct? If so, you have some options:

- **Include the Permias.mdf** into your Project B by right-clicking your solution root in the Solution Explorer, and click 'Add Existing File'.
- **Rename Permias.mdf** to something else, or put it in a different folder/location, and make sure to update all references in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a different database name.

EDIT: Kidding! (Sort of.)